# LaTeX equations in org-mode file missing when it's converted to word docx using pandoc?

Tags: org-mode, latex, pandoc

I am trying to export org-mode files to docx using pandoc. One issue is that **some** equations involving external LaTeX packages do not show up in the exported word document.

For example, the following org file has inline latex that can be displayed inline using `C-c C-x C-l`:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{proof}


$\phi,\cdots, \psi$ are some symbols


$\infer{A}{ \infer{B}{      B11\land B12\land B13       &       B21\land B22\land B23   }   & C }$
```

But when exported to word using

```
pandoc test.org -o test.docx
```

There is a warning. And in the output word document, the second equation involving an external package `proof.sty` either disappears or is displayed as latex source code (within `$$ ... $$` though). I have tried various alternatives including using `$$` or `\[` or `BEGIN_LATEX` in the source org file, but couldn't get the equation across. The equations show up correctly when displayed inline inside org or exported to PDF. It's just missing in the docx.

*Does anyone know how to get pandoc to recognize the org header `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{proof}` and convert the equations associated with the packages there?*

(This is with Emacs 27 and Ubuntu 20.04. The warning message is below)

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math \infer{A}{ \infer{B}{      B11\land B12\land B13       &       B21\land B22\land B23   }   & C }, rendering as TeX:
  \infer{A}{ \infer{B}{      B11\land B12\
        ^
  unexpected control sequence \infer
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\tag", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting to ODT and then using `soffice` to convert to `docx`?

Comment: @NickD I tried `pandoc test.org -o test.odt`, and got the same warnings. Exporting to odt inside emacs, the generated odt file shows latex source in it. `$\phi,\cdots, \psi$ are some symbols `

Comment: I went looking a little bit and did not find a way to deal with this. `pandoc` seems OK with the out-of-the-box, run-of-the-mill math environments, but it does not seem to support a plugin/extension mechanism to support additional environments (like `proof` above).

Comment: @NickD Thanks a lot for looking into this.